# Check if FTP entry is file or folder with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am working on a script for connecting to an FTP and then download the content.

Now my problem is to detect whether a each item is a folder or a file.
My first idea was to try and use `ftp_chdir`, but this would require me to suppress the error using `@`, and I don't wish to do this (I don't wish to suppress errors, but instead prefer to handle them correctly).

Is there another way to check if a my items are files or folders?

Comment: Try `explode()` on every name of the file/folder taking `.` (dot) as a separator; if you are getting extension i.e. two array elements then it is file otherwise folder.

Comment: Ashwani: Sadly it is possible to have dots in folder names

Comment: user1844933: is_dir() does not seem to work for ftp functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad thing about trying the `ftp_chdir` is not the need to suppress the errors. That's ok, as long as you have a legitimate reason to expect an error. It's rather the side affect of changing the directory.

If I take that direction, I'd try the [`ftp_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php) instead, as it does not have any side effects. It should fail for directories and succeed for files.

---

The ideal solution is to use the `MLSD` FTP command that returns a reliable machine-readable directory listing. But PHP supports that only since 7.2 with its [`ftp_mlsd` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php). Check the `"type"` entry for `dir` value.

Or, there's an implementation of the `MLSD` in user comments of the `ftp_rawlist` command:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#101071

First check if your FTP server supports `MLSD` before taking this approach, as not all FTP servers do (particularly [IIS and vsftpd don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49528887/850848)).

---

Or, if you are connecting to one specific server, so you know its format of directory listing, you can use the [`ftp_rawlist`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php), and parse its output to determine, if the entry is file or folder.

Typical listing on a *nix server is like:

```
drwxr-x---   3 vincent  vincent      4096 Jul 12 12:16 public_ftp
drwxr-x---  15 vincent  vincent      4096 Nov  3 21:31 public_html
-rwxrwxrwx   1 vincent  vincent        11 Jul 12 12:16 file.txt
```

It's the leading `d` that tells you, if the entry is a directory or not.

---

You may be lucky and in your specific case, you can tell a file from a directory by a file name (i.e. all your files have an extension, while subdirectories do not).

Comment: I have desided to use ftp_rawlist and check each line. Seems to work rather well. All the servers I am using are running Nix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need this in 2018+

You can use [ftp_nlist](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ftp-nlist.php). 
For files you'll retrieve array with only one element (the file path itself), for directories you'll have at least two items in array `.` and `..`, and if no file or directory exists there will be an empty array returned.

Comment: That's a behavior you indeed get with *some* FTP servers. But it's no way portable across various servers. And definitely it's not backed by FTP specification (the specification does not allow "listing" a file).