# ftplib MLSD command gives 500 Unknown command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

I have been using `ls = f.mlsd()` to get list of files and timestamp from ftp but it gives me

```
ftplib.error_perm: 500 Unknown command
```

Is there any problem with ftp server? do i need to install anything on the server to get this command working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the fact, MLSD is nothing but a protocol extension introduced in RFC 3659 that may be not supported by some FTP servers. If you care about portability, it's better to use `f.nlst()` instead.

If changing something on server is acceptable for you, then I suggest you switching to proftpd which has MLSD support as a part of it's mod_facts extension.

Comment: Thanks i have switched to proftpd with mod_facts extension and MLSD command works fine now

Answer (score 4):

`MLSD` command was not a part of an original FTP standard. It was added only later in [RFC 3659](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659), in 2007. While that's still quite some time ago, even now some major FTP servers do not support it. Particularly IIS and vsftpd.

If you need timestamps and yet you need to talk to a server that does not support `MLSD` command, you have two options:

1. Use [`FTP.dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.dir) (`LIST` command). And parse proprietary format of file listing to retrieve the timestamps.
2. Use [`FTP.nlst`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst) to retrieve a list of files (and folders). Then, use [`FTP.voidcmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd) to send [`MDTM` command](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3659#section-3) for each of the listed files. `MDTM` returns a file timestamp in a standardized format.

   Obviously this is a way less effective than the previous approach, but you won't have to deal with a proprietary formats of directory listings.

   Note that `MDTM` is not supported by all FTP servers either, but it is more widely supported than `MLSD`, although both commands come from the same RFC (3659). Particularly one of common Linux FTP servers, vsftpd, supports `MDTM`, but not `MLSD`.

---

For a code to implement both approaches see my answer to:
[How to get FTP file's modify time using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026709/850848)

Comment: I have switched to proftpd and enabled mod_facts and MLSD command works fine now