# List folders only from FTP server with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I would like to list all my folder on my web application **without** the files in it. At the moment I'm using this code but this will give me all files and folders:

```
//Connect
$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login = ftp_login($conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpassword);

//
//Enable PASV ( Note: must be done after ftp_login() )
//
$mode = ftp_pasv($conn, TRUE);

$file_list = ftp_nlist($conn, "/webspace/httpdocs/brentstevens.nl/u_media/$uid/");

foreach ($file_list as $file)
{
    // process folder
}
```

But this will output all files and folders. How can I adjust this code to only serve the folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server supports `MLSD` command and you have PHP 7.2 or newer, you can use [`ftp_mlsd` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-mlsd.php):

```
$files = ftp_mlsd($conn, $path);

foreach ($files as $file)
{ 
    if ($file["type"] == "dir")
    {
        echo $file["name"]."\n";
    }
}
```

If you do not have PHP 7.2, you can try to implement the `MLSD` command on your own. For a start, see user comment of the `ftp_rawlist` command:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#101071

---

It is not easy to implement this without `MLSD` in a way that works for any FTP server. See also [Check if FTP entry is file or folder with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29799181/850848).

But if you need to work against one specific FTP server only, you can use [`ftp_rawlist`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php) to retrieve a file listing in a platform-specific format and parse that.

The following code assumes a common *nix format.

```
$lines = ftp_rawlist($conn, $path);

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $tokens = explode(" ", $line);
    $name = $tokens[count($tokens) - 1];
    $type = $tokens[0][0];

    if ($type == 'd')
    {
        echo "$name\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server not supports MLSD command or you have PHP <7.2 and ftp_rawlist marks directory as `<DIR>`

```
function getList($connection, string $path): array
{
    $rawlist = ftp_rawlist($connection, $path) ?: [];

    $items = [];
    foreach ($rawlist as $data) {
        $item = array_combine(['date', 'time', 'size', 'name'], preg_split('/\s/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
        $item['type'] = $item['size'] === '<DIR>' ? 'dir' : 'file';
        $item['size'] = (int)$item['size'];

        $items[] = $item;
    }

    return $items;
}

function getFileList($connection, string $path): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter(getList($connection, $path), function ($file) { return $file['type'] === 'file'; }));
}

function getDirList($connection, string $path): array
{
    return array_values(array_filter(getList($connection, $path), function ($file) { return $file['type'] === 'dir'; }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php` function and with regular expression parse type which in your case is letter `d`

Comment: Many thanks for your fast reply. Can you give me an example. I'm not really familiar with ftp-rawlist.